# LaTeX, Two columns, Listings and Numbers

Tags: latex, listings

I'm trying to get a report done and I have a small problem with the twocolums and the line numbering in listings.

The document is on two columns :

```
\documentclass[8pt,[...],a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
```

The listings can end up either on the left or the right column. The problem is: if I put

```
\lstset{numbers=left,frame=tb,[...]}
```

the space between the columns is not sufficient when the listing is on the right column and the text from the first column is written over.

Is there any way to ask the listings to put the line numbers "outside" ? I know I can modify the space between the columns, but I would prefer to move the numbers on the side.

Thanks

Comment: This is a question for superuser.com.

Comment: Oh you big grouch. LaTeX questions are perfectly fine for SO, this one for example requires interaction between two different macro packages to provide a solution, possibly going into the guts of those packages and exporting local variables to global ones and having the other package behave based on those variables. Even a simple kludge like wrapping the listing in a \mbox and resizing, or quickly defining a new environment with custom margins is more programming than selecting the correct option in an application.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but have your tried changing the value of \columnsep?

Comment: are you making the document two columns via a class option or via the multicols package?

Comment: This is an question for http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Try the following (you might have to adjust the sizes):

```
\lstset{xleftmargin=5mm,framexleftmargin=5mm}
```